# How can you do something with each argument in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

Given this function:

```
function foo( a,b,c ) {
    //
}
```

How can you do something, say use console.log() for each argument? I know you can see the arguments by using the arguments keyword. Arguments seems to return what looks like an Array (but is of type "object" [suprise.. not]) but it doesn't support .forEach, I am using Chrome.

I tried modifying the function to this, and expected it to work:

```
function foo( a,b,c ) {
    arguments.forEach(function( arg ){
        console.log( arg );
    });
}
```

You get the error that TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `arguments` object doesn't have a `forEach` method, so you need to iterate over it either with a `for` loop, or a `for...in` loop.

```
​function foo () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);    
    }
}

foo("Foo", { "bar": 0 }); // Output: Foo, Object {bar: 0}
```

Or

```
​function foo () {
    for (var arg in arguments) {
        console.log(arguments[arg]); 
    }    
}

foo("Foo", "Bar"); // Output: Foo, Bar
```

Comment: Won't using `for..in` on `arguments` also iterate over the `length`, `callee` and other properties?

Comment: @RocketHazmat No. The length property isn't enumerable. The descriptor for `length` in the example above is `{value: 2, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}`.

Comment: In your second example why is arguments[arg] required? Why can't you just console.log(arg)? I see, I had a typo before, the arg keyword is an index.

Comment: @CaleyWoods Because 'arg' represents a key, and not a value. So we have to pass that key once again to the `arguments` object in order to get the corresponding value.

Comment: Jonathan Sampson - I've accepted your answer as I feel it answers the exact question I asked. It didn't address my next question (which is no fault of yours) but some of the other answers did illustrate using ```Array.protoype.forEach.call()``` which answered my next question of "How do you make arguments respond to ```forEach```?".

I believe your ```for...in``` solution is even more readable than calling ```.forEach```.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Any idea why now in my editor JSHint balks saying bad for in variable 'arg'? I tried change it to 'x' as well and it doesn't make a change.

Edit: after some research it appears the correct way to do is to prefix 'arg' with var so it's defined in the local scope. 

```for ( var arg in arguments )```

Comment: @CaleyWoods You're correct regarding var; I'm sorry for missed that, but good for you that you're linting.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use a hack:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (arg) {
    console.log(arg);
});
```

`arguments` isn't an array, but it's close enough that you can apply Array's prototype and use the regular array functions.  We're just grabbing Array's implementation and applying it forcefully to arguments.

Comment: This is again what I was headed towards. I commented an explanation on phant0ms answer.

Comment: You could further simplify this to `Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, console.log, console)` if you only want to log it, but I doubt that's what you're after.

Comment: tjameson that is correct. I have another function I'm looking to call and just wanted a clean way to do that and avoid:

  someFn(a);
  someFn(b);

Answer (score 2):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
// convert to array
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
args.forEach...
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for. The answers about using a regular for loop were good answers but it let me to the question, "If arguments doesn't respond to forEach, how can I make it do that?". This answer answers the question I hadn't asked yet.

With that said, is this something that needs to be done within each function or can I permanently convert the arguments object into an array (not saying I'd want to, just curious.) ?

Comment: @CaleyWoods No, you can't do it permanently, you'll have to do it for each function.

Answer (score 1):

Do a loop on `arguments.length`. `arguments` isnt an Array so it doesn't have the `forEach` prototypal method.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i<l; ++i ) {
  doSomething( arguments[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal `for` loop.

```
function foo( a,b,c ) {
    for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Or you can convert it to a real array.

```
function foo( a,b,c ) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.forEach(function( arg ){
        console.log( arg );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var show_args = function (){

    for(var ar in arguments){
        console.log(arguments[ar])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the "arguments" into an array by calling the array slice method on it:

```javascript
function foo(a, b, c) {
  var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  argArray.forEach(function(x) {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Submitted the the same solution the very same second... Impossible! This must be one of those strange quantum world things.

Comment: @phant0m, low-hanging fruits exist in the normal world too. :)

Comment: @bzlm I'm more surprised by the timing than the contents ;)